# "Create Shipping Label" for free shipping

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

Magento 2 offers the "create shipping label" functionality only for orders where the customer selected a shipping method that supports shipping labels through its API. So, if they for instance use the "free shipping" method, there is no backend option for creating labels.

Is there a way, via configuration or extension module, that the backend administrator can create a shipping label with a carrier of their choice?

Basically, our client wants to offer free shipping and then choose which carrier they ship with based on the order contents and destination.

Comment: You will have to develop custom module for this